# how to create a pdf form ? i need to insert textbox and radio button controls in it

Tags: c#, pdf, forms, textbox, itext

how to create a pdf form ? i need to insert textbox and radio button controls in it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/)?

> iText# (iTextSharp) is a port of the
>   iText open source java library for PDF
>   generation written entirely in C# for
>   the .NET platform.